# Finding complex limit when conjugate is involved

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Any ideas on how to solve this?

$$\lim_{Z \to Zi} (Z^2- \bar Z)$$

I would just plug in $ Zi $ but if it were not for the conjugate which isn't something you can just derive from a complex number. I've also tried expanding the complex numbers, $ Z = x + iy $ and $ \bar Z = x - iy $ and doing limits axis-wise but then you'd end with two different limits...

Comment: What does $x\to Zi$ mean? $Zi=-y+ix$ and $x$ is real, so presumably it means that $|x+y-ix|\to0$ which implies that $x$ and $y$ both tend to 0.

Comment: Sorry, i've been copy pasting Mathjax from related questions and forgot to change the x to Z

Comment: Ok, so you ask the same question, what does $Z\to Zi$ mean. Taking real and imaginary parts, we have $x+iy\to -y+ix$, so $x\to-y$ and $y\to x$. As before that implies $z\to0$.

Comment: wow, did not see that. Guess this is why I'm doing a re-sit. Thanks man

Comment: Maybe copy paste that as answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the limit is unusual. What does it mean for $Z\to Zi$. Taking real and imaginary parts, we have $x+iy\to-y+ix$, so $x\to-y$ and $y\to x$. That implies $Z\to 0$.